# iframe resizing issue on iOS (not your standard responsive iframe)

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe

I have an iframe that is responsive, but sized differently on smaller (mobile) screens. On larger screens it's the common responsive iframe where it scales proportionally to fit within the container using the padding-top %. And on smaller screens the container becomes 80vh height, 100% width. The iframe content then has it's own horizontal slider (which will also eventually be gryo controlled).

It all works fine on desktop browser, and other devices (bunch of Androids) but not on iOS. The iframe still fills the height correctly but doesn't max out at the container width. Instead it keeps original proportions and becomes wider than its container.

Not the easiest to explain in words, so:

[Screenshot on Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBpIj.png)

[Screenshot on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSPC2.png)

[Live demo](https://activearticles.com.au/embeddable/test/?embed_preview=true)

View it on desktop and resize the window it actually does exactly what I need, including once you get down to smaller mobile size. Or load it on an Android device (I'm using BrowserStack). You'll notice the iframe width stops at the container bounds, and you get the scroller within the iframe.

But on iOS (iPhone) it's not doing that. Instead the iframe just extends out beyond the container bounds, and the parent page becomes horizontal scroll.

Any help appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**
Found a semi-related post that suggests adding the following CSS for the iframe element

`width: 1px; min-width: 100%; *width: 100%;`

It didn't do the trick for me, however when I add that to the body element of the iframed content (which I also control), it resolves the issue.